# A species that is warm-blooded when a juvenile, but cold-blooded (or at least lukewarm-blooded) when an adult

Tags: science-based, biology, evolution, dragons, metabolism

In my world, there is a species of squamates from the *Toxicofera* clade named dragons (their scientific name is *Draco draco*). Some of their characteristics include:

1. In comparison to human beings, they have a better sense of smell, a better sense of eyesight (they are tetrachromats), and a better sense of taste, but they have a worse sense of hearing, and a worse sense of touch.
2. They have the ZW sex-determination system.
3. They are adolescents all their lives, in the sense that they never stop growing (the record for the longest dragon is 12.75 meters long).
4. They are oviparous, and they have between one and eight eggs by offspring, the average is 3.4.
5. They are 0.25 meters long when they are born, and they start reproducing when they are 2.5 meters long, this length happens when they are at least 25 years old.
6. They are facultative bipeds like chimpanzees (in other words, they can walk bipedally but not often, and they have a hunchback gait).
7. Their wings are their arms, and juveniles can fly as well as wild turkeys, but adults only glide like colugos, but, when they are at least 5 meters long, which happens whey they are at least 100 years old, they do not fly or glide at all.
8. They are almost immune to cancer like naked mole-rats.
9. They have human-level intelligence when they are juveniles, but elephant-level intelligence when they are adults.
10. Adults have gorilla-level strength.
11. They are as social as emperor penguins when they are juveniles, but when they are adults, they are almost never found in groups larger than five individuals.
12. They are sequential omnivores: juveniles are omnivores with carnivorous tendencies like raccoons, and adults are omnivores with herbivorous tendencies like squirrels.
13. Juveniles are as warm-blooded as polar bears, but adults are lukewarm-blooded like great white sharks.
14. Juveniles are as aggressive as wild boars, but adults are as peaceful as basking sharks.

So, I wonder how could a species of tetrapod have a radical change of multiple things (including control of body temperature) when becoming an adult?

Comment: "Why?" is a very open ended ask. Evolution isn't logical. Or the critter was deliberately created that way maybe for a specific functional reason, maybe just because the creator had arbitrary whims that they choose to indulge. Regardless brainstorming an explanation isn't an appropriate question for this site.

Comment: surprisingly losing intelligence is the hardest thing, everything else is fairly minor changes but loosing a lot of brain tissue is hard to get naturally in tetrapod. the only organisms that lose brain tissue on a large scale lose the brain entirely.

Comment: @john Does going from human to elephant count as losing intelligence? I took it as a step sideways. Anyway, lowering the intelligence of a creature 'temporary' isn't that hard. Starvation or lower oxygen levels in the blood can cause that. 

By lowering the average temperature of the dragon, we can lower the activity of their organs. All organs, _including_ their brain. It wouldn't surprise me if a drawn-out process of slowing their brain activity while ageing has negative consequences on their intelligence.

Comment: @vinzzz001 elephant is a big step down from human, it might be comparable to gorilla but a big difference from human. that's a big step down like if you are starving enough to loose that much you are likely dead in a few days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is point #14. Being ectotherms their metabolism level is linked to their body temperature: the warmer they are the more active they are and thus more aggressive they can be. Because the juveniles are very aggressive they have evolved to be semi-endotherms and generate extra body heat by some mechanism such as muscle vibrations or whatever to boost their metabolism level to support their high aggression. But this uses up a lot of energy, so as they mellow out as they mature they no longer need to do this and so they gradually revert back to their full ectothermic mode.

Also, as they grow the square-cube relation will mean that they no longer need to generate much internal heat to maintain a reasonable (but not as high as juveniles) body temperature, because they lose less heat to the environment compared to their body mass even as full ectotherms than the smaller juveniles.

Comment: For dinosaurs, the vulnerability of their young was a major factor towards their extinction. If the reptile is warm-blooded in its youth (thus with mammal-like energy) but becomes ectotherm in their adolescence (large reptile with few natural predators and modest food demands) it could dominate the ecosystem to that day.

Answer (score 3):

## Stoking the Flame

Being an [endotherm](https://www.washingtonpost.com/lifestyle/kidspost/ever-wondered-about-warm-blooded-and-cold-blooded-animals/2015/11/27/575d30ca-6c57-11e5-aa5b-f78a98956699_story.html)([warm-blooded](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/7080)) means that an animal generates warmth by raising its metabolism for the purpose of generating heat in order to maintain a constant body temperature.

Your dragons are simply endotherms in the traditional sense constantly maintaining their own body temperature. They won't turn [ectotherm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ectotherm)(reliant on outside factors for heat, which is often called cold-blooded), but their average body temperature lowers with age.

They generate too little warmth to sustain themselves using movement, or it might cost them more warmth than it creates. Instead, they got a unique organ("flame") somewhere high up in their torso that generates a lot of heat. The heat is spread around their body by way of their blood. This causes their blood to be warm.

When the dragon grows, its "flame" does grow too. It is, however, very costly to keep their "flame" burning, becoming far worse when they grow because of square-root shenanigans. The answer to this? Burn less hot. They simply lower the activity of their "flame" to be able to keep up with demand, which also lowers their body temperature. As a side effect, lower body temperatures lower the activity of other organs, which further lowers energy expenditure.

**Largely Lethargic**
As above, their level of activity, or energy level, scales inversely with size. This can be because they are becoming less hot-blooded (and hot-headed) when they grow up. Their blood being cooler when larger causes large variants to become sluggish, and even lethargic at larger sizes.

Young dragons can feed themselves on prey animals. As their size increases, so does their need for food. At a point, a dragon won't be able to sustain itself hunting and will be pushed to use less and less energy hunting to offset its relative lack of energy gained from food. This has them go from actively hunting, to waiting in ambush, to just slowly eating whatever is in reach of their mouths.

Once they are of a large size, nearly no prey is worth catching because becoming more active requires stoking their "flame", which costs a lot of their reserves. More than most prey would offset. Their intelligence and lethargy combined make them learn this somewhen when transitioning to herbivorous meals. Dragons may still hunt extremely large prey, eat carrion they stumble across, or eat meat that walks directly into their mouth.

**End result**
 Dragons become colder-blooded and less aggressive when growing in size. That said, if a dragon is threatened, it will stoke its "flame" to fight back. Even if it means dying of starvation/hypothermia later.

PS: This can cause fun side effects.

- Dragons like living near sources of heat(volcanoes) so they can lower their energy expenditure even more.
- Very large dragons hibernate for long periods in times of scarcity because sustaining their flame becomes nearly impossible otherwise. (hibernating wasteland dragons)
- The "flame" can also be used as a breath weapon, but using the breath weapon too much will cause them to die of hypothermia.

Answer (score 1):

### I can see two options

Your best bet is that have not really evolved to live as long as they do, surviving past adulthood is something that only started recently perhaps with the extinction of their only predator. As their metabolism winds down and they get too overgrown they survive but not well, they are literally suffer from severe aging.

Another good option is something like human menopause, old individuals stop reproducing and instead take over guarding nests of their offspring's eggs. Too big to fly their diet changes, its not that they stop wanting meat, they just can't catch it. The brain degenerating is still tricky, intelligence is a huge survival advantage, but maybe their lower food intake just can't support the same brain volume. Maybe loosing some intelligence is necessary to make them single-minded enough to watch nests for most of the day all day without getting bored, although that would still be very boring for an elephant. And this only works if they are only passive UNTIL you get too close to the nest, then they should be very violent. Lots of animals have different behavior as juveniles vs adult you age just adding another stage. T-rex and in fact many dinosaurs are known to be far more social as juveniles than as adults, but dinosaurs produce a LOT of eggs because most don't make it to adulthood. .

In both cases this means "adults" are not really the adults but past the adult stage.